# Nonzero matrices whose adjugate is the zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I will denote by $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ the adjugate matrix of $A$ i.e. the transpose of the cofactor matrix,which has the propery that $A\cdot \operatorname{adj}(A)=\operatorname{adj}(A)\cdot A=\det A \cdot I_n$.
I am curious to find nonzero matrices(no matter the dimension) whose adjugate is the zero matrix. I could only come up with examples such as 
$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 2 \\
3 & 3 & 3 \\
\end{pmatrix}$,but I want to see some other ones.

Comment: another example:  $\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 &  3 \\ 2 &  4 &  6 \end{matrix}\right)$

Comment: @Math Guy: If $A$ is an $n\times n$-matri with $rk(A) < n-1$, then $adj(A) = 0$, that is, $adj(A)$ is the zero matrix; if $rk(A) = n-1$, then $rk(adj(A)) = 1$; if $rk(A) = n$, then $rk(adj(A)) = n$. That's it.

Comment: @Moritz that's right, I hadn't thought about using this!

Answer (score 3):

For all $n \ge 2$, the adjugate matrix $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is $0$ if and only if the rank of $A$ is at most $n-2$.

To find a matrix $A$ of rank at most $n-2$, write $A= B\cdot C$, where $B$ is size $n\times (n-2)$, and $C$ size $(n-2)\times n$.

Answer (score 2):

Any matrix of the form$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\\alpha a&\alpha b&\alpha c\\\beta a&\beta b&\beta c\end{bmatrix}$$will do.